# jquery Load div one by one, without automatic looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display some divs one by one in same position. Something very similar with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VesQ/chw3f/5/).

```
// First hide them all
$("#fades div").hide();

function fades($div, cb) {
    $div.fadeIn(100, function () {
        $div.fadeOut(100, function () {
            var $next = $div.next();
            if ($next.length > 0) {
                fades($next, cb);
            }
            else {
                // The last element has faded away, call the callback
                cb();
            }
        });
    });
}

function startFading($firstDiv) {
    fades($firstDiv, function () {
        startFading($firstDiv);
    });
}

startFading($("#fades div:first-child"));
```

But I need the last div to show after all (no looping).
If the visitor need to see the loop once again, they need to press or click a text or button.
thanks

Comment: where's the cb callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <div id="fades">
    <div>Hello #1</div>
    <div>Hello #2</div>
    <div>Hello #3</div>
    <div>Hello #4</div>
    <div>Hello #5</div>
    <div>Hello #6</div>
    <div>Hello #7</div>
    <div>Hello #8</div>
    <div>Hello #9</div>
    <div>Hello #10</div>
</div>
<input id="looponclick" value='Click Me!' type="button"></input>
```

**Javascript CODE:**

```
function fades($div) {
// First hide them all
$("#fades div").hide();
$("#looponclick").hide();

$div.fadeIn(100, function () {
    var $next = $div.next();
    // Fade out the current element only
    // if you have next element
    if ($next.length > 0) {
        $div.fadeOut(100, function () {
            fades($next);
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#looponclick").show();
    }
});
}
fades($("#fades div:first-child"));

$('#looponclick').click(function(){
    fades($("#fades div:first-child"));
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/chw3f/105/

Answer (score 1):

The minimal change would be to remove the `else` case, that's the code that restarts the whole thing. And then move the `if` test to surround the fade out code.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chw3f/95/

```
function fades($div, cb) {
    $div.fadeIn(100, function () {
        var $next = $div.next();
        if ($next.length > 0) {
            $div.fadeOut(100, function () {
                fades($next, cb);            
            });
        }
    });
}
```

(You could tidy it up by removing the now unsed `cb`.)

> *"If the visitor need to see the loop once again, they need to press or click a text or button"*

Just call `startFading()` from a click handler on the button in question: http://jsfiddle.net/chw3f/101/

Answer (score 0):

```
    // First hide them all
$("#fades div").hide();

function fades($div, cb) {
    $div.fadeIn(100, function () {
        if (currentDivCount < totalDivCount-1) {
            $div.fadeOut(100, function () {            
                currentDivCount++;
                var $next = $div.next();
                if ($next.length > 0) {
                    fades($next, cb);
                }
                else {
                    // The last element has faded away, call the callback
                    cb();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function startFading($firstDiv) {
    fades($firstDiv, function () {
        startFading($firstDiv);
    });
}

var totalDivCount = $("#fades div").length;
var currentDivCount = 0;

startFading($("#fades div:first-child"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chw3f/100/

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(!$next.length) return false;` to stop the function from the last. And call the function that you want when clicked.

```
function fades($div, cb) {
    $div.fadeIn(100, function () {
        var $next = $div.next(); //variable declaration is shifted here
            if(!$next.length) return false;
        $div.fadeOut(100, function () {

            if ($next.length > 0) {
                fades($next, cb);
            }
            else {
                // The last element has faded away, call the callback
                cb();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chw3f/102/)